# After sync, iTunes files appear but won't play. Error message says files couldn't be found

Tags: itunes

Can you help, please?

Am attempting to populate iTunes on a Laptop that was factory reset.
I installed a new version of iTunes for Windows 7! iPod Classic is working fine all songs play. Songs are transferred from iPod to an **empty** iTunes library via the iPod Control feature. All songs transfer and copy; Sync is unchecked. iPod is disconnected. All songs in iTunes now appear with an error mark and will not play. "Original file cannot be found". This is a factory reset laptop so no original files exist.

How can I resolve this issue? The files are not corrupt on the iPod before transfer.

I have repeated the process several times by deleting the iTunes library contents. I have also deleted and reinstalled iTunes.

I am not a "techie" so simple step-by-step instructions are needed, please.

Comment: See https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/transfer-music-ipod-computer/ You can't do this on a Mac natively, as the iPod never mounts as a visible drive like it does on Windows, so there are likely to be fewer people in this group who fully understand the procedure.

Comment: It’s been a long, long time since I used iTunes on Windows 7, but if I remember correctly, you’re not copying (there’s no copy function) files from the iPod to the PC.  You’re importing the songs into the library but leaving them on the iPod.  The files aren’t corrupt, they’re just not accessible because you disconnected the iPod.

Comment: @Allan - that makes sense - Apple never designed the iDevice to be the 'master' only the 'slave' to its associated iTunes computer instance. This might need one of those 3rd party 'data stealers'.

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone who responded with suggestions. I had saved some songs on an extrrnal hard drive, so all is not lost.